# How do the Bruhat cells of based on upper triangular matrices relate to the cells of lower triangular matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question, lie-groups

Let $B_+$ be the subgroup of $GL(n)$ of upper triangular matrices and let $B_-$ be the subgroup of lower triangular matrices. Let $\pi \in S_n$ and $P_{\pi}$ be the corresponding permutation matrix.

Is there any relation between the sets $B_+P_{\pi}B_+$ and $B_-P_{\pi}B_-$? Are they equal to eachother? Disjoint? Thanks in advance

Comment: It helps to think about the Bruhat decomposition for $GL_n$ as a generalisation of Gaussian elimination/row reduction (I answered this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637921/why-bruhat-decomposition-in-gl-n-case-is-the-gauss-decomposition/3606165#3606165) but you can also find it elsewhere on MO I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any Borel ($B_+$ or $B_-$) contains the maximal torus, the sets you've written down are not disjoint. But by my comment, they do not coincide either (although all Borels are conjugate to each other - this also holds for more general groups beyond $GL_n$).